# remove() not working in vanilla javascript - WordPress REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

The remove() method is not working in my Vanilla Javascript code, even though the Element is being selected correctly (logging "theDeletedBlock" in the console gets returned normally).

I tried selecting the parent, and it did not work.
I even tried simply adding a "hidden" class, but it does not work either.

**The post does get deleted, but the element does not get removed!**

Here is my code...

---

### HTML

```
<div class="student-names-in-block">
</div>

<div>
    <div class="block-text-contents">
        <span class="highlight-text"></span>
        <span class="block-text"></span>
    </div>

<a class="day-time" target="_blank" href="http://te-io.local/class-description/tuesday-2000-2-2/">tuesday 20:20-21:20</a>

    <div class="block-buttons">
        <a target="_blank" class="room-button" href="https://whereby.com/topenglish">Top</a><a target="_blank" class="report-button" href="http://te-io.local/class-description/tuesday-2000-2-2/">Report</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block-buttons admin-buttons">
    <a class="delete-button">Delete</a>
</div>
```

...

---

### JavaScript

```
...

//Delete the clicked class
deleteClassDesc(classID){

    const http = new XMLHttpRequest()        

    const params = '?class-description=' + classID

    http.open("DELETE", scheduleLocalize.teSiteUrl + "/wp-json/top/v1/schedule" + params , true)
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    http.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", scheduleLocalize.nonce)

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (http.readyState == 4){
            if(http.status == 200){
                console.log('Success! Class ID: '+ classID)

                const theDeletedBlock = document.querySelector(`[data-class-id='${classID}']`)
                
                //this line does not work
                theDeletedBlock.remove()

            }else if (http.status == 400) {
                console.log('Admin: There was an error 400. Please try again, or contact us.');
            }
            else {
                //something else other than 200 was returned
                console.log(`Admin: Error: Please try again, or contact us.`);
            }
        }
    }
    
    http.send();

    //alert('Delete class ID: ')
}
```

Comment: Where is `data-class-id` in html

Comment: From where you are calling `deleteClassDesc`

Comment: data-class-id is in the parentElement of the posted html (StackOverflow is stripping my code).

Comment: deleteClassDesc is in a js that is part of my plugin, it has been enqueued properly. Btw, this does not work locally or online.

Comment: In vanilla you have to make use of [node.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild). In your example `theDeletedBlock.parentNode.removeChild(theDeletedBlock)` should do the trick.

Comment: I cannot seem to understand why nothing works! Selecting the parent did not work. I literally added the same line as part of my attempts: `theDeletedBlock.parentNode.removeChild(theDeletedBlock)`  --And it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

So, the html was being generated from another JS file, and so it seems that I was generating this specific part of html outside of one parent's parent DIV or, more specifically, outside of the right JS loop that as generating each generation of child blocks.

I do not know exactly why, but organizing that in the JS that generated the html solved the problem.

Thanks to the ones who answered!